# Excel VBA refering to cell value as #DIV/0

Tags: excel, vba

Value on cell :

```
K12 = 0,    
K13 = 0 ,    
K14 = K13+K12
```

which K14 display as `#DIV/0!`

If the value on K14 is more than 7, MsgBox will pop up.
But since the value is #DIV/0!, VBA does not work.

```
Sheets("Passdown Format").Select
Range("K14").Select
If Range("K14").Value > 7 Then
MsgBox "More than 7"
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

In the VBA code you can check if the cell contains a numeric value:

```
Sheets("Passdown Format").Select

If IsNumeric(Range("K14")) Then
    If Range("K14").Value > 7 Then
        MsgBox "More than 7"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "No numeric value in cell K14"
End If
```

If the cell contains "DIV/0", by checking the content of the cell if it is numeric, it will no longer run into Type mismatch error.

Comment: awesome. thanks Stellarator. Totally forgot IsNumeric.

Answer (score 1):

K14 is showing  #DIV/0!, because K12 and K13 are not numbers, instead they are strings. Change them to numbers (i.e. remove the commas?) and your code will be fine.

```
K12 = 0   
K13 = 0   
K14 = K13+K12
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I overlook strins in K12 and K13.

Answer (score 1):

If K14 is reporting #DIV/0! then there is something somewhere on the sheet (not in the code) that is involving the division by 0.

Just as a test I created a spreadsheet and put 0 in K12, 0 in K13 and generated the sum of these two in K14; as per your example. I got 0.

So, the issue is on the sheet, not in the code.

If you want the code to offer a response to the error, then iserr() will do this, but I feel that is not where you want to go.

EDIT: I hadn't assumed the commas were in K12 or K13, as the other answer suggested, but if they are correct then they are totally correct; the cells would then contain text not numbers, and would generate the error you have.